# Mac OS Java 7 applet+smartcard issue

Tags: java, macos, applet, smartcard-reader

We have applet that uses smartcards to sign something. Everything was OK until new java update on Mac OS.
I'll explain. When macos had java 6 and special plugin for it, everything worked. But now they removed their plugin, and users must download browser-plugin for java 7 from Oracle web site.

Applet still sees Card Reader but doesn't see smartcard in it. 
We use reader.isCardPresent() method, and it returns "false", no exceptions etc. like everything ok and there is no card in cardreader. We restore backup of the os, when there was 6 java and MacOS's own plugin, everything works. But we have many clients that have just bought new iMac or MacBook, they cannot use 6 java and apple's plugin.

Everything works on Windows. 
We don't use any deprecated methods. Seems like problem with Oracle's plugin for Mac OS.

Anyone had similar problem or may be you have any ideas.

Comment: *"Anyone had similar problem or may be you have any ideas."* If anybody had it is likely reported in the [Sun bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/) (Java is now owned by Oracle, but apparently Sun still owns the bugs).  ;)

Comment: Maybe is the same problem with Linux 64 bits. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376257/accessing-javax-smartcardio-from-linux-64-bits

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan possibly, I thought about that one too, but in that case there must be a difference between the browsers, maybe another JRE is deployed or something.

Comment: Found in bug database http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7195480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just make some tests: take code from [sample](http://code.google.com/p/java-sample-programs/source/browse/trunk/JavaSamples/src/src/com/moodykettle/pcsc/PCSC.java?r=9) and slightly modify it. Run the sample on jdk1.7.0_09 in macosx 10.8.2. Pcsc framework 1.4.0.

**terminal.isCardPresent() return false, but card can be accessed.** Bug exist when java running both 32 and 64 bit mode. Pcscd running in 32 bit mode only, because generic pcsc driver is still 32-bit only.

In pcscd debug log i see some parsing errors in SHMMessageReceive, so bug may be in java or in the pcsc framework (`winscard_msg.cpp`).