# PCSC does not return anything on linux, the card reader is connected

Tags: java, linux, pcsc

I am trying this, to read the card with PCSC framework. But it does not return anything at all.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.smartcardio.*;

public class Blog {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   // Display the list of terminals
   TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
   List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
   System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);

   // Use the first terminal
   CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

   // Connect wit hthe card
   Card card = terminal.connect("*");
   System.out.println("card: " + card);
   CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

   // Send Select Applet command
   byte[] aid = {(byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01};
   ResponseAPDU answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid));
   System.out.println("answer: " + answer.toString());

   // Send test command
   answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
   System.out.println("answer: " + answer.toString());
   byte r[] = answer.getData();
   for (int i=0; i<r.length; i++)
    System.out.print((char)r[i]);
   System.out.println();

   // Disconnect the card
   card.disconnect(false);
  } catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Ouch: " + e.toString());
  }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
run-single:
Terminals: []
Ouch: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

By using other tools it works, but cant figure out why Java code is not showing?

```
root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# ps -e | grep pcsc
16399 ?        00:00:00 pcscd
root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# service pcscd status
 * pcscd is running
root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# service pcscd restart
 * Restarting PCSC Lite resource manager pcscd                                                                                                                   [ OK ] 
root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 032: ID 076b:3021 OmniKey AG CardMan 3121
root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# opensc-tool -l
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    No              Generic CCID Reader 00 00

root@sun-M14xR2:/var/tmp# pcsc_scan 
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.20 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.3
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Generic CCID Reader 00 00

Fri Apr 19 05:30:22 2013
Reader 0: Generic CCID Reader 00 00
  Card state: Card removed, 

Fri Apr 19 05:30:59 2013
Reader 0: Generic CCID Reader 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card, 

Fri Apr 19 05:31:04 2013
Reader 0: Generic CCID Reader 00 00
  Card state: Card removed, 


Fri Apr 19 05:33:31 2013
Reader 0: Generic CCID Reader 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 98 13 40 0A A5 03 01 01 01 AD 13 11

ATR: 3B 98 13 40 0A A5 03 01 01 01 AD 13 11
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 98, Y(1): 1001, K: 8 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 13 --> Fi=372, Di=4, 93 cycles/ETU
    43010 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 53763 bits/s
  TD(1) = 40 --> Y(i+1) = 0100, Protocol T = 0 
-----
  TC(2) = 0A --> Work waiting time: 960 x 10 x (Fi/F)
+ Historical bytes: A5 03 01 01 01 AD 13 11
  Category indicator byte: A5 (proprietary format)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 98 13 40 0A A5 03 01 01 01 AD 13 11
    Belgium Electronic ID card
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because driver problem in Linux. Please install the proper driver for this hardware: https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/14919

And then i got at-least code feedback in my terminal.

Comment: I have installed drivers for ACR122U ,now program argument path for libpcsclite.so file is valid, but still not getting terminals in java code.

where else I am getting positive `pcsc_scan` results, showing card details and status

Answer (score 4):

I found another workaround here

[Accessing javax.smartcardio from Linux 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376257/accessing-javax-smartcardio-from-linux-64-bits)

> I think I found a workaround for this as I just had a similar problem.
>   In a bugreport from ubuntu it says that the javax.smartcardio library
>   searches for the PC/SC library in the wrong directory.
>
> So running my app with the setting as below worked for me
>
> -Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so

Comment: This solution worked for me but in my machine (Ubuntu 18.08) the file was different:
-Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arch linux then it might be happening due to not having usb chip/ smartcard interface devices driver not installed.
You can install it by using "sudo pacman -S ccid".